# Using regex and android for categorizing different fields

Tags: java, android, regex, ocr

I am currently trying do a business name card scanner app. The idea here is to take a picture of a name card and it would extract the text and categorize the text into different EditText.

I have already completed the OCR part which extract out all the text from a name card image.

What I am missing now is to make a regex method which can take this entire text extracted from OCR and categorize the name, email address, phone number into their respective fields in EditText.

Through some googling I have already found the regex formulas below:

```
private static final String EMAIL_PATTERN =
            "[a-zA-Z0-9\\+\\.\\_\\%\\-\\+]{1,256}" +
                    "\\@" +
                    "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,64}" +
                    "(" +
                    "\\." +
                    "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,25}" +
                    ")+";


private static final String PHONE_PATTERN =
            "^[89]\\d{7}$";


private static final String NAME_PATTERN =
            "/^[a-z ,.'-]+$/i";
```

Currently I am **just** able to extract out the email address using the below method:

```
public String EmailValidator(String email) {

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);

        if (matcher.find()) {

            return email.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end());

        } else {

            // TODO handle condition when input doesn't have an email address

        }

        return email;
    }
```

I am unsure of how to edit the **^above method^** to include using all the 3 regex patterns at once and display them to different EditText fields like (name, email address, phone number).

**--------------------------------------------EDIT-------------------------------------------------**

After using @Styx answer,

it has a problem with the parameter whereby how I used to pass the text "textToUse" to the method as shown below:

[image]

I have also tried passing the text into all three parameters. But since the method is `void`, it cannot be done. Or if I change the method to a `String` instead of `void`, it would require a return value.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code. The function takes in the recognize text and split it using break line symbol. Then run a loop and determine the type of content by running a pattern check. Whenever a pattern is determined then the loop will go into next iteration using **continue** keyword. This piece of code also able to handle situation where 1 or more email and phone number appear on a single business card. Hope it helps. Cheers!

```
public void validator(String recognizeText) {

    Pattern emailPattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
    Pattern phonePattern = Pattern.compile(PHONE_PATTERN);
    Pattern namePattern = Pattern.compile(NAME_PATTERN);

    String possibleEmail, possiblePhone, possibleName;
    possibleEmail = possiblePhone = possibleName = "";

    Matcher matcher;

    String[] words = recognizeText.split("\\r?\\n");

    for (String word : words) {
        //try to determine is the word an email by running a pattern check.
        matcher = emailPattern.matcher(word);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            possibleEmail = possibleEmail + word + " ";
            continue;
        }

        //try to determine is the word a phone number by running a pattern check.
        matcher = phonePattern.matcher(word);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            possiblePhone = possiblePhone + word + " ";
            continue;
        }

        //try to determine is the word a name by running a pattern check.
        matcher = namePattern.matcher(word);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            possibleName = possibleName + word + " ";
            continue;
        }
    }

    //after the loop then only set possibleEmail, possiblePhone, and possibleName into
    //their respective EditText here.

}
```

Comment: I was just trying something similar myself! Thanks for your answer. However, now there is a problem as the method has several parameters and it has error passing the text over to the method. **Please check my edited post** :)

Comment: @MattDonalds What are you trying to achieve to be exact? Do you plan to guess the content by doing match pattern?

Comment: @MattDonalds may I get an example of what the recognized text would look like? Does each content is separate by a symbol, for example, a space " ", pipe "|", comma",".

Comment: Hi, I am actually doing an OCR function whereby the user takes a picture of a business card and it extracts the text from the image. recognizedtext is actually the output of result from another activity where this OCR function resides in String format. An example would be anything like "name, address, phone number" or anything you can find on a business card, i would say it is separated by space. however, for address there would be spaces in between (but let's ignore address for now)

Comment: @MattDonalds it would be a challenge when we try to determine what is the content because we probably looking at a String like this, "Matt Donalds 60149127389 test@gmail.com. If the string look like this then it is required to first split the string into a list by space. Then run pattern checking on each element to determine it is an email / phone. If both checking fail then categorize them as name.

Comment: Most of the time, my OCR function will break up the name, address and email with break lines in between, instead of space. Would that require the spilting of strings as well?

Comment: @MattDonalds the sequence of name, address and email is depends on the image it scans, am I right?

Comment: @MattDonalds the code able to handle situation where 2 or more email and phone number appear on a single business card.

Comment: Thank you so much, tested and it works. Your answer is really clear and informative :)